# (CefSharp & WinForms) Is it possible to make the background transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm testing around with CefSharp and i would like to know if there is a way to make the Chromium Web Browser background transparent?

Why do I ask that? There are many different opinions and I hope you can help me find the answer faster.

I hope someone could help me.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: No. Only the `WPF` version supports transparency,

Comment: If https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/136/add-support-for-windowed-mode-transparency/diff is ever merged into `CEF` then we can look at adding support to `WinForms`, until then it's simply not possible.